# Background Task asp.net

Tags: asp.net, backgroundworker, azure-sql-database, background-process

I would like to create a background task which continuously inputs the location from a mobile to a database and in a website, I would like to get the same location immediately as it changes.

I am using an SQL Azure database. so pushing and polling are not an option. Also I am not sure if I can use a cache since the location continuously changes.

I think I have to create some infinite loop which carries on a task continuously. But how does this concept work?

Does this simply involve the create of a thread and a while(true) { ... } ?

Comment: used signal R and managed to achieve what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a similar situation, and the approach I went for was to have an special page (/StartJob.aspx?AccessKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx), that when hit with the right access key, would start a job cycle.

I then setup a "Cron Job" using www.setCronJob.com, to call this page at regular intervals.  This service can notify you by email if it fails too.

Comment: how would you be able to get the visitors connected to write to database? I like this website though very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the timer control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404.aspx

sounds like something that could help out with achieving what you need :)

Comment: thank you for your comment. When I used this method and created a tick every second the server started to crash continuously :(

Comment: Something else you should or could look at is http://nodejs.org/ Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run across distributed devices.

Comment: infact node.js is exactly what you need.

Comment: i am viewing videos on node.js. but I don't have any idea where to start from? Can you please help me? How can I apply it to my asp.net website. I have found many links for windows azure and node.js but I cannot find a simple tutorial to show me how I can get information from my database frequently! (if this is, afterall, the way i should be using it!

Comment: I'm really sorry but i'm still an amateur with node. It might be worth starting up a new question with this as the tag and such. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: I think I have changed my mind since I couldn't grasp where to start with. Hopefully after 6 searching I am thinking that Queues of windows azure can be an answer. I will try to follow this example http://www.developerfusion.com/article/120197/using-the-queuing-service-in-windows-azure/

Comment: let me know how you get on. I'm sure I'll need something similar in the future as well :)